# Issue when moving object with mouse position Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made the script bellow to move an object smoothly with mouse position, it works smoothly but I have one issue in this script, when I click and move the mouse, the object move immediately to (0, 0, 0) position then it start moving with the mouse movement.

How can I fix that, so the object move from the last position not from (0, 0, 0) position?

**Script:**

```
float Speed = 50f;
float sensitivity = 5f;

Vector2 firstPressPos;
Vector2 secondPressPos;
Vector2 currentSwipe;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        firstPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        secondPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        currentSwipe = new Vector2(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

        if (firstPressPos != secondPressPos)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(currentSwipe.x / 200, currentSwipe.y / 200, transform.position.z), sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand kind of what you want.

You want to be able to click anywhere and the object should than only follow the relative movement of the mouse not the exact position, right?

Otherwise you could just use

```
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, secondPressPos, sensitivity * Time.deltaTime)
```

But I don't understand why you devide the `currentSwipe` by `200` .. you probably have your reasons.

Anyway, what I understand you want requires that you additionally also store the `initialPos` the position the object has at the moment your mouse button goes down. Than later you add to that initial position the `currentSwipe` instead of using it alone ( = adding it to `0,0` )

```
float Speed = 50f;
float sensitivity = 5f;

Vector2 firstPressPos;
Vector2 secondPressPos;
Vector2 currentSwipe;

private Vector2 initialPos;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        firstPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        // store the current position
        initialPos = transform.position;
    }
    // I would just make it exclusive else-if since you don't want to 
    // move in the same frame anyway
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        secondPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        currentSwipe = secondPressPos - firstPressPos;

        if (firstPressPos != secondPressPos)
        {
            // Now use the initialPos + currentSwipe
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, initialPos + currentSwipe / 200, sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note** that in general it depends on your needs but that kind of using `Lerp` never actually reaches the exact position ... it only gets very close and very slow.